# Overriding existing keydown event listener with a userscript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jwplayer, userscripts

I've been trying to override an event listener on a site for quite some time now and I have an issue with a video player (jwplayer). Key events are bound and captured and are not able to be easily overriden.

Here's the script:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name        test
// @author      test
// @version     1.1.5
// @match       *://*.example.com/*
// @require     https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

/* globals $ */

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
  if (e.ctrlKey && !e.shiftKey && !e.altKey && !e.metaKey)
  {
    switch (e.keyCode)
    {
      case 37:
        alert('37');
        // JQuery code to change the page
      break;
      case 39:
        alert('39');
        // JQuery code to change the page
      break;
    }
  }
}, true);
```

Testing is done like this:

```js
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'https://third-party.example.com/js/jwplayer8/jwplayer.core.controls.html5.js';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);

script.onload = function() { 
    alert( 'loaded' );
}
```

Jwplayer's controls are just a simple switch-case, and calls the same keys as I do, among others: keys 37 and 39. Changing the keys I'm watching for to something else doesn't change anything.

When the player isn't in focus, everything works as expected. When the player has started and captures a keypress, it breaks the userscript.

On page load, the site's script loads twice. First one opens a dialogue box simply saying "loaded" as it is supposed to. However, on second load the dialogue box, while still saying "loaded" now has a title called "The page at https://third-party.example.com says:" instead of no title like before.

Likewise, using the shortcuts <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Arrow</kbd> (left or right) produces identical results. The alerts say either only "37" or "39" like they are supposed to, and the dialogue box has no title, like expected.

Once the jwplayer is in focus, though, the dialogue box reflects the one saying the script loaded. The title becomes "The page at https://third-party.example.com says:" and then either "37" or "39" as the information within.

My original plan was to simply unfocus the jwplayer, but considering that the alerts execute properly but any code following it doesn't, has made that difficult.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 phases in which you can handle events in JavaScript. One is the event capturing phase where the event flows from the parent to the child. The other is the event bubbling phase, where the event flows bottom up (child to parent).

You can turn on capturing, by setting the third parameter to `.addEventListener()` to `true`. You can then use `event.stopPropagation()` to ensure that the event doesn't trickle down to the videoplayer.

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    // Any other code
}, true); // <= This tells JS to use the event capturing phase
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Before I start the video, or generally just click on the html5 player, the script works fine. But even with this, it still doesn't work once I've actually clicked on the player and started or paused the video.

Comment: Sorry, accidentally pressed enter haha! It sadly still doesn't work. But I added `e.stopPropagation();` to the beginning and set the third parameter to `true`.

Comment: It looks like the videoplayer is eating up the event. When the player loses focus(For example, when you click anywhere else in the document), does the functionality work as expected? Also, which player are you using?

Comment: Ah yes, I probably forgot to mention. It does work as expected when the video player isn't in focus, and the issue certainly is that it is eating/overriding my event once the player does get focus.

I think the video player should be jwplayer. That's what I can see from the DOM at least.

Comment: I've tried some more, without any real progress.

Thanks to some alerts I set up, I know the code _does_ execute. It simply doesn't do so correctly. I set the alerts to say the key case codes. When the jwplayer isn't in focus, the dialogue box simply says "37" or "39" and nothing else. But when the jwplayer _is_ in focus, it says "The page at https://third-party.example.com says:" and then the key case code, so 37 or 39.

The code doesn't execute properly however, as after the alert prompt disappears, nothing else happens.